# Google Web Fonts don't load in FF 4.0 or IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, firefox4, google-webfonts

I'm using Google Web Fonts API in my WordPress theme and stumbled upon a weird problem: fonts don't load in FF4 or IE9 (it's fine in Safari, Chrome, Opera, and IE8...).

I checked the source of the page, as well as the PHP code that creates the links to Google Fonts stylesheets and everything works fine - the links are created:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='webfont-body-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans&#038;ver=3.1.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='webfont-head-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gruppo&#038;ver=3.1.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

and the styles are applied as well:

```
<style type='text/css'> 
    body, input, textarea { font-family: 'PT Sans', 'Helvetica Neue' Arial, sans-serif; } 
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-family: 'Gruppo', 'Helvetica Neue' Arial, sans-serif;     letter-spacing: normal; } 
</style>
```

It works fine in other browsers, but FF4 and IE9 have a problem with it and completely ignore the Google Fonts.

Here's the link to the site/theme in question: http://dev.gentlecode.net/agency

Comment: This Google Web Fonts API use cufon fonts so can you check this if google use cufon for this then you can informed to google for regenerate this cufon for ie9 or ff4 because they both doesn't support old cufuns.

Comment: I don't think it's the problem but if you're not using cufon anymore, you can get rid of `<script type="text/javascript">Cufon.now();</script> ` near the bottom of your markup.

Comment: I'm using both (set up in theme options panel, either Google Fonts or Cufon) and forgot to only display this if Cufon is chosen, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your CSS in the question, it's missing a comma after `'Helvetica Neue'`.

Comment: You, sir, are a hero. Thanks so much, I would've never noticed it after staring at this code for so long.

Comment: @Justine: No prob. Also, Arial's probably a little redundant in that font stack.

Answer (score 1):

well, an alternative to it would also be maybe fontsquirrel =)